# Send file using POST from a Python

Tags: python, post, file-upload, python-requests, vk

I have the url, where I need to send a video file.
For this reason i wrote this code:

```
import requests

upload_url = 'https://cs506200.vk.me/upload_video_new.php?act=add_video&mid=21844505&oid=21844505&vid=171170813&fid=0&tag=93bb46ee&hash=e238f469a32fe7eee85a&swfupload=1&api=1'
file_ = {'file': ('video.mp4', open('video.mp4', 'rb'))}
r = requests.post(upload_url, files=file_)

print (r.text)
```

I get an error:
{"error":"invalid file"}

But in this case:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
 </head>
 <body>  
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="https://cs506200.vk.me/upload_video_new.php?act=add_video&mid=21844505&oid=21844505&vid=171170813&fid=0&tag=93bb46ee&hash=e238f469a32fe7eee85a&swfupload=1&api=1" method="POST" target="_blank">

<input type="file" name="video_file" />

<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
 </body>
</html>
```

All working fine.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using the wrong field name:

```
file_ = {'file': ('video.mp4', open('video.mp4', 'rb'))}
```

That names the field `file` while your form uses `video_file`:

```
<input type="file" name="video_file" />
```

Using the right field name is important, correct your parameters:

```
file_ = {'video_file': ('video.mp4', open('video.mp4', 'rb'))}
```

Comment: You're right! For two days I couldn't solve this problem. Thank you!