# Laravel + Python request not working but in Postman it works

Tags: python, post, request, postman

I'm trying to send some data with a python script from my raspberry pi, i already had a similar question and some answer me not what i was looking for but it kind of works you can check it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48798462/python-to-laravel-upload-mp4-file) the thing is i was trying to make a base64 encode send it and then decode it and save it, now i'm trying a different way I'm trying to send some data in a `multipart/form-data` the problem is that in my python script when i'm trying to send the video it seems that it's not sending any video, but when i send it from Postman works perfectly, i tried to see what was the code on Postman.

Here is the postman code to send it to my php server

```
import requests

url = "http://192.168.1.208:8080/api/createvideo"

payload = "------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"files\"; filename=\"20180215-033512.mp4\"\r\nContent-Type: video/mp4\r\n\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"ip_address\"\r\n\r\n10.10.10.110\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"date\"\r\n\r\n2018-02-14 18:27:20\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--"
headers = {
    'content-type': "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW",
    'Accept': "application/json",
    'Content-Type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    'Cache-Control': "no-cache",
    'Postman-Token': "50de5d50-e0f9-d2ab-6b37-aee8aa127bb3"
    }

response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```

Postman image of what i'm doing:
[View post on imgur.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPFxx.jpg)

And here is my python code here is where i'm building the request:

```
 file = {'files': open(filename,"rb"),
         'date': file = {'file': open(filename,'rb'),
         'ip_address': self.api.get_ip()}
 r = self.api.postvideo(file)
```

Post request service code:

```
def postvideo(self, file):
        return requests.post(self.url+'createdevice',files=file)
```

why would it be fine in Postman, i'm wondering what I'm missing because when it arrives in my Laravel Server it shows empty, here is what I'm doing in Laravel

```
if ($request->hasFile('files')) {
            $device = Device::where('ip_address',request('ip_address'))->first();

            $path = public_path().'/video/'.$device->id.'/';
            $file = str_random(8).'.mp4';
            $file_name = $path.$file;

            $request->file('files')->move($path,$file);
            $video = Video::create([
                'date' => request('date'),
                'device_id' => $device->id,
                'video' => $file_name
            ]);

            return response()->json([ 'data' => $video]);
        }

        return response()->json([ 'data' => 'No Video Attach'],404);
```

p.s I already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12385179/how-to-send-a-multipart-form-data-with-requests-in-python/12385661#12385661)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i did a few mistakes i didn't really make the same result but it works, first i changed this:

```
file = {'files': open(filename,"rb"),
         'date': file = {'file': open(filename,'rb'),
         'ip_address': self.api.get_ip()}
```

for this as you can see i split the data and the file:

```
file = {'files': ('video.mp4',open(filename,"rb"))}
data = {'date': file = {'file': open(filename,'rb'),
             'ip_address': self.api.get_ip()}
```

I don't really know what happened but i did a `time.sleep` too before all this because i was using a subprocess and apparently the video wasn't able used it on read mode so that helped me too.

There other thing was to make the post request like this:

```
return requests.post(self.url+'createvideo',files=file,data=data)
```

I did this so that when it arrives in Laravel i could used them properly like this:

this to read the file and relocate it

```
$request->file('files')->move($path,$file);
```

And this to fetch any data:

```
$request->input('ip_address')
```